# How to prove that the following sum converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume $a_n $ is a sequence such that $a_n >0 $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N} $, Such that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} $ diverge.

How can I prove that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{S_{n}^{2}} $$

converge, where $ S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} $  The partial sum sequence.

I tried to use cauchy criteria, i.e, given $\varepsilon >0$, I want to prove that there exists $N $ such that for any $n_1 , n_2 $, we have $ \sum_{n=n_{1}}^{n_{2}}\frac{a_{n}}{S_{n}^{2}} < \varepsilon $.

So

$$ \sum_{n=n_{1}}^{n_{2}}\frac{a_{n}}{S_{n}^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{S_{n_{1}}}\sum_{n=n_{1}}^{n_{2}}\frac{a_{n}}{S_{n}}\le\frac{1}{S_{n_{1}}}\left(\frac{a_{n_{1}}}{a_{1}+...+a_{n_{1}}}+\frac{a_{n_{1}+1}}{a_{1}+...+a_{n_{1}+1}}+...+\frac{a_{n_{2}}}{a_{1}+...+a_{n_{2}}}\right)\leq\frac{1}{S_{n_{1}}}\left(\frac{a_{n_{1}}+...+a_{n_{2}}}{a_{1}+...+a_{n_{1}}}\right) $$

$$ =\frac{1}{S_{n_{1}}}\left(1+\frac{a_{n_{1}}+...+a_{n_{2}}}{a_{1}+...+a_{n_{1}}}\right) $$

But I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: What do you mean by "so $\sum a_n$ diverges" in the first line ?

Comment: Are you assuming $\sum_{n}a_n$ diverges, or are you deducing $\sum_{n}a_n$ diverges based off the assumption that $a_n>0$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Sorry if It was'nt clear. I assume that the sum converge.

Comment: You're assuming the sum converges? Or diverges? Please clarify in your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a series diverges, what happens when we divide by partial sums squared?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296263/if-a-series-diverges-what-happens-when-we-divide-by-partial-sums-squared)

Comment: Also [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296203), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411817),...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$$\frac{a_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_n S_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{S_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{S_n}$$

Answer (score 0):

The convergence follows from
$$\sum_{n = 2}^m\frac{a_n}{S_n^2} \leq \sum_{n = 2}^m \frac{a_n}{S_n S_{n - 1}} = \sum_{n = 2}^m \left(\frac 1{S_{n - 1}} - \frac 1{S_n}\right) < \frac 1{S_1}.$$
Thus the infinite sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{S_n^2}$ is bounded from above. Since all summands are positive, the series converges.

Note that it doesn't matter whether $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ diverges or not.